# advanced custom field (ACF) + Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

I use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields plugin) for Categories, Contact Form 7 and/or Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension / Contact Form 7 Modules: Hidden Fields.
I will try to explain with example what I want to achieve...

I create categories where i fill some additional data using ACF. In my case, every category is Company Name. I use ACF, to fill Copmany Phone, Company E-mail, Company Address, etc.

After than, I create posts, where every post is associated with some category.
In this posts, I use Contact form with shortcode directly in single.php (echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="206" title="Contact form EN"]' );)

Here coming my dilemma and BIG question:
I want in this Contact form, to load pre populated data from category where is this post. (eg. If post is in category Company A, I want this post to preload Contact form with hidden fields from their category).

Answer (score 0):

you could insert the fields you need to populate the contact form in your url as query parameters and then get them with contact form

> www.yourwebsite.com/?your-name=foo

```
[text* your-name default:get]
```

see https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

Comment: But how exactly i can insert in posts url's ACF fields, that is associated with their category? Because in posts i not have any ACF, only in Categories. I not want to put in every post again and again same data like Company Name, Company Phone, Company E-mail etc.